# When I going to Disable Twig template cache , Fatal error

Tags: theming

When I going to Disable Twig template cache , Fatal error . i.e

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Error: Unsupported operand types in
>   Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment->__construct() (line 69 of
>   core\lib\Drupal\Core\Template\TwigEnvironment.php).

I followed below steps :

1.Copy and rename the file from sites/example.settings.local.php to  sites/default/settings.local.php
2.Open settings.php file in sites/default and uncomment these lines:

```
if (file_exists($app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php')) {
include $app_root . '/' . $site_path . '/settings.local.php';
}
```

3.Uncomment these lines in settings.local.php

```
$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';
$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null';
```

4. Open development.services.yml in the sites folder and add the following code

   ```
    parameters:
   twig.config:
   debug: true
   auto_reload: true
   cache: false
   ```
5. Rebuild the cache and your good to go

My development.services.yml code :

`parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
  debug: true
  auto_reload: true
  cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory`

Comment: Are you sure the services.yml is still valid after you've edited it in point 4? Can you post the yml file?

Comment: Yes  services.yml file is inside sites\default 
my development.service.yml code 
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
  debug: true
  auto_reload: true
  cache: false
services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory

Comment: services.yml file I have to write any things ??

I followed 
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2016-05-21/disable-twig-template-cache

Comment: I meant the `development.services.yml` you've edited. Can you post the entire file?

Comment: @Arif Are the whitespaces correct in your .yml file? I've added a comment in the original posting on drupal.org

Comment: ok got it .. my mistake.. Thank u all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The least hassle way is to [install Drupal Console](https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/getting/project.html)

Then run the command `drupal site:mode dev` (turns off caching and turns on twig debug)

Once you're done, run `drupal site:mode prod` (turns off twig debug, turns caching back on).